# How to detect MTP/Portable Device using VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, device, mtp

How to do that? I've been googling it and still get no answer. Recently I'm using MTPSharp library but there's a bug when no device detected. Any other libraries or code maybe? Thanks.

Comment: I fear your question could be a bit more substantiated. I doubt your question can be answered as it is now. Do you try to develop a web api, a client-side program, a streaming website,... Also; a more detailed explanation of "a bug when no device detected" would help...

Comment: Hi, My application is based on Android debug bridge command line tools. But I make it to graphical user interface. And what i want is to detecting an Android phone every connected to PC, if connected the app will enable all functions or when disconnected the app will disable all functions. So I need the code to detect it automatically.